# copy jTextPane text to clipboard

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a form which contains a `jTextPane` and a `jButton`, I've set the `jTextPane` `Accessible Description` to `text/html`, now I want when I click on the `jButton` to copy the content of the `jTextPane` to my clipboard, I tried this code :

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection (jTextPane1.getText());
        Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
        clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
    }
```

but when I past, it past the text as an HTML format.

How can I solve this probelm ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are 2 clipboards in Java (a local one and a system one, which you are using). [Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82)'s an example that uses the system clipboard. Take a look and try this  getClipboardContents method:

```
public String getClipboardContents(Clipboard clipboard) {
    String result = "";
    if (clipbloard != null){            
        //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        boolean hasTransferableText =
          (contents != null) &&
          contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        if ( hasTransferableText ) {
          try {
            result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
          }
          catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex){
            //highly unlikely since we are using a standard DataFlavor
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As I see it, the problem is setting or getting the content, its ant converting the text from the JTextpane to plain text (stripping off the HTML tags)

Answer (score 1):

When I use Ctrl+C I get text copied to the clipboard without HTML. You can use the default Action with the following code:

```
Action copy = new ActionMapAction("Copy", textPane, "copy-to-clipboard");
JButton copyButton = new JButton(copy);
```

See [Action Map Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) for more information on how this works.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to select all the text in the textpane and then copy.

```
private void btnCopyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    textPaneLogs.selectAll();
    textPaneLogs.setFocusable(true);
    textPaneLogs.copy();
}
```